# Avoiding/Preventing Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536 - Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

There are couples of solutions I found but none for me. I would want to avoid in hitting that, my project is never that big if I specifically get the classes that i need [A very uncomfortable way].

My question is : Is it possible to exclude files[which had never been used in my project] that are in file dependency and module dependency in Android Studio?

My project is referencing libraries such as

1. Maven-Gplay Services
2. Maven-SupportApp Compat
3. Maven-v4
4. Maven-crouton
5. Maven-gson
6. Maven-imageloader
7. Maven-cwacmerge
8. Maven-gcm-server
9. Maven-facebook-android-api
10. Maven-simple-xml
11. Module-android-ngn-stack
12. Module-my-other-lib
13. Module-my-lib
14. File-aws-android-sdk-2.0.5-ddb.jar
15. File-aws-android-sdk-2.0.5-ddb-mapper.jar
16. File-aws-android-sdk-2.0.5-core.jar
17. File-mqtt-3.jar

Now after I have added Module-android-ngn-stack, I hit the `Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536` , and the solution I found was a script in `xml` and proguard but these solutions only targets cure and not prevention.

and question again :
Is there any way that I could exclude some classes in File-dependency or Module dependency? like exclude `com.example.ClassthatArentUsed` in File or Module dependency?

I hope i made myself clear and I hope there will be a prevention-like solution.

Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome to attempt to apply ProGuard for shrinking only (no obfuscation) in debug builds. Your main problem is that you have two large "kitchen sink" libraries (Google Play Services and the Amazon AWS SDK).

Comment: ah yes i think i should, still im trying to understand how in android-studio. cause its different in eclipse and originally the project is from eclipse. :(

Comment: thanks for `lib-cwacmerge` anyways its very useful to me.

Comment: @CommonsWare seems like i managed to shrink the methods by changing my file dependency to maven dependency. i dont get why?

Comment: Perhaps you did not need one of the dependencies that you thought you did. By using an artifact in a repository (e.g., Maven Central), you only pull in the actual dependencies that are needed. If you manually do it via local JARs, you might add a dependency that is not needed. Android doesn't know that (at least sans ProGuard), and so it would compile in the unnecessary code. This is all just a guess, though, as to how your steps addressed your problem.